# Proof of contraposition theorem using logical (semantic) entailment definition

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, metalogic

I have been reading some older course material from Propositional Logic and I stumbled on a question, and I am unsure on how to start the proof. The question is:

Prove the following theorem (contraposition theorem), by using the definition of logical entailment |=.

> W ∪ {ϕ} |= ¬ψ iff W ∪ {ψ} |= ¬ϕ

The definition of |= is:

> Let W be a set of closed formulas. Then W entails ϕ, W |= ϕ, if and
> only if Mod(W ) ⊆ Mod(ϕ)

Where Mod(W) is the class of all models of W.

My first idea is to somehow use the Mod to show equivalence of both of the sides or to somehow work through all the possible cases of the left side formula and show that in every case, the left side entails the right side.

Comment: By contradiction. The two implications are similar, thuss consider LEFT TO RIGHT and consider a valuation that satisfies W and psi and does not sat not-phi, i.e. satisfies phi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{1}$. Let $W \cup \{ \phi \} \vDash \neg \psi$ where $\phi, \psi$ are wffs and $W$ is a set of wffs. By definition of $\vDash$, we have

$$ \text{Mod}(W \cup \{ \phi \}) \subseteq \text{Mod}(\neg \psi) $$

and by definition of $\subseteq$, we have

$$ \forall x [x \in \text{Mod}(W \cup \{ \phi \}) \to x \in \text{Mod}(\neg \psi)] $$

In other words, for every interpretation $x$, if $x$ is a model of every formula in $W \cup \{ \phi \}$, then $x$ is a model of $\neg \psi$. Without loss of generality, let $x = a$ hereafter. So, by substitution, we have

$$ a \in \text{Mod}(W \cup \{ \phi \}) \to a \in \text{Mod}(\neg \psi) $$

$\mathbf{2}$. Now, assume $a \in \text{Mod}(W \cup \{\psi\})$. Of course, this implies $a \in \text{Mod}(W)$ and $a \in \text{Mod}(\psi)$.

$\mathbf{3}$. Furthermore, for purposes of proof by contradiction, assume $a \in \text{Mod}(\phi)$.

$\mathbf{4}$. Now, consider that if $a \in \text{Mod}(W)$ and $a \in \text{Mod}(\phi)$, then $a \in \text{Mod}(W \cup \{\phi\})$. Thus, by Modus Ponens with lines $2$ and $3$, we indeed have $a \in \text{Mod}(W \cup \{\phi\})$. However, according to line $1$, this implies that $a \in \text{Mod}(\neg \psi)$ and we have already stated on line $2$ that $a \in \text{Mod}(\psi)$. Hence, we have a contradiction, and if we keep all other assumptions in place, then our assumption on line $3$ must false. In other words, it must *not* be the case that $a \in \text{Mod}(\phi$), implying that $a \in \text{Mod}(\neg \phi)$.

$\mathbf{5}$. Thus, if $a \in \text{Mod}(W \cup \{\psi\})$ as stated on line $2$, then $a \in \text{Mod}(\neg \phi)$. Now, the choice of $a$ was arbitrary, so we know for every interpretation $x$, if $x \in \text{Mod}(W \cup \{\psi\})$, then $x \in \text{Mod}(\neg \phi)$. In other words,

$$ \forall x [x \in \text{Mod}(W \cup \{\psi\}) \to x \in \text{Mod}(\neg \phi)] $$

By definition of $\subseteq$, we have

$$ \text{Mod}(W \cup \{ \psi \}) \subseteq \text{Mod}(\neg \phi) $$

and by definition of $\vDash$, we have

$$ W \cup \{ \psi \} \vDash \neg \phi $$

$\mathbf{6}$. So, if $W \cup \{ \phi \} \vDash \neg \psi$ is the case on line $1$, then we have shown that $W \cup \{ \psi \} \vDash \neg \phi$ is the case on line $5$. Formally speaking,

$$ W \cup \{ \phi \} \vDash \neg \psi \Rightarrow  W \cup \{ \psi \} \vDash \neg \phi $$

$\mathbf{7}$. Now, consider that the choice of $\phi$ and $\psi$ in the above formula is abitrary. In other words, we could easily exchange the symbols and repeat the above proof to show

$$ W \cup \{ \psi \} \vDash \neg \phi \Rightarrow W \cup \{ \phi \} \vDash \neg \psi $$

$\mathbf{8}$. Since both $ W \cup \{ \phi \} \vDash \neg \psi \Rightarrow  W \cup \{ \psi \} \vDash \neg \phi $ and $ W \cup \{ \psi \} \vDash \neg \phi \Rightarrow W \cup \{ \phi \} \vDash \neg \psi $ hold true, we have

$$ W \cup \{ \phi \} \vDash \neg \psi \Leftrightarrow  W \cup \{ \psi \} \vDash \neg \phi $$

by definition of the metalogical biconditional $\Leftrightarrow$. This completes the proof.

Comment: I see now, thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score -1):

$W \cup \{\phi\} \models \neg \psi \iff W \cup \{\psi\} \models \neg \phi$ means: $\mathrm{Mod}(W \cup \{\phi\}) \subset \mathrm{Mod}(\neg \psi) \iff \mathrm{Mod}(W \cup \{\psi\}) \subset \mathrm{Mod}(\neg \phi)$.

($\implies$) Suppose $\mathcal{M} \in \mathrm{Mod}(W \cup \{\psi\})$. Suppose $\mathcal{M} \notin \mathrm{Mod}(\neg \phi)$. Then, $\mathcal{M} \in \mathrm{Mod}(\phi)$. But, as $\mathcal{M} \in \mathrm{Mod}(W \cup \{\psi\})$, $\mathcal{M} \in \mathrm{Mod}(W)$, hence $\mathcal{M} \in \mathrm{Mod}(W \cup \{\phi\})$, and $\mathcal{M} \in \mathrm{Mod}(\neg \psi)$, i.e., $\mathcal{M} \notin \mathrm{Mod}(\psi)$. But, as $\mathcal{M} \in \mathrm{Mod}(W \cup \{\psi\})$, $\mathcal{M} \in \mathrm{Mod}(\psi)$, hence we have a contradiction, and it must be that $\mathcal{M} \in \mathrm{Mod}(\neg \phi)$.

$(\impliedby)$ Exact analogue to the above proof.

$\square$

Comment: fyi OP defines ⊨ using the general subset ⊆ and not the proper subset ⊂ as you do in your response. I also believe you're sacrificing clarity for conciseness; it would be helpful if you elaborated some about how you were drawing certain inferences.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy I am not using the proper subset, it is but a difference in notation. $\subset$ is deemed the general subset, while $\subsetneq$ denotes the proper subset.

Comment: actually, we are both right! I've learned authors use $\subset$ to refer to the proper subset *or* general subset, depending on preference. Since OP uses $\subseteq$ to refer to the general subset, it is probably best to stick with similar notation to avoid confusion. Or, if you're going to use notation that is inconsistent with OP, then define the notation.